# Is there any way to await and catch in javascript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am kind of new to async/await in javascript by have used suspend functionalities in Kotlin before. Is there any way to await and catch error if any in js. (without writing try catch). If not what is the right way to do this.

For example consider this snippet, async function `a`:

```
let a = async () => {
   // does io and returns result
}
```

Now, consider a function `b` which calls `a`. Can I write it in this clean way:

```
let a = async () => {
   const result_of_a = (await a()).catch(() => { // handle error }) 
   // work with `result_of_a`
}
```

Rather than

```
let a = async () => {
   var result_of_a = null
   try {
       result_of_a = await a()
   } catch (e) {

   }
   // work with `result_of_a`
}
```

Is there any other pretty way of writing the above sub-routine

Comment: .then takes two callbacks, where the second one is invoked on error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can. If you think `.catch` is cleaner perhaps you should just use promise syntax. Personally I use both, depending on the context. But I favor async due to [promise hell](https://medium.com/@pyrolistical/how-to-get-out-of-promise-hell-8c20e0ab0513)

```
let asyncFn = async () => {
   const result = a().then(...).catch(...) 
}
```

Comment: Promise hell is my problem too, async syntax gets so bad with try catches

Answer (score 0):

Use `catch` on a promise that is returned from your function. You mixed up two different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way :

```
   let b = async () => {
       const result_of_a = await a().then(()=>{
         // handle success response here and return value
        },
        ()=>{
           // handle success response here and return value you want
          }
       )

   // You will get value return in `result_of_a`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the sake of readability i would rather use a function which uses `try/catch`

```
async function errorControl(funcName) {
try{
   const data = await funcName()
    return [data, null]
  } catch (err) {
    return [null, err]
  }
}
```

and then you can use it like this

```
const b = async () => {
 const [result_of_a, err] = errorControl(a())
 if(err)
// do something 

}
```

it can also be use with `promiseAll`

```
const reqMultiple = async () => {
     const [result_of_a, result_of_b] = await Promise.all([
      errorControl(a()),
      errorControl(b())
     )]
  const [data_of_a,err_of_a] = result_of_a
 //...
    }
```

i prefer this way over the then/catch style because you don't have nested code which is a pain to read